# compareTo() and member pointers

Tags: java

I have a member that is a pointer to an array.  Comparing two instances of the class, I want to do a simple sort on the *address* of the array member, and *not* the contents.

I can do equality checking on the array member, `==`, but not `<` nor `>`.  How can I compare the reference addresses of the arrays?

Comment: Not sure but using `arrayMember.hashCode()`, you can perform, ==, <, > operations

Comment: Why would you want such a thing as comparing addresses of arrays in Java?

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez the arrays are immutable and represent some internal state at some point in time and I want to cache expensive derived result-sets in a ConcurrentSkipList so I need comparable, even if sort order can be arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

Internally, `Object.equals()` method compares object's hashCodes. You can do the same thing here. Something like :

```
Integer[] intArray = new Integer[10];

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    intArray[i] = i;

if(intArray[0].hashCode() > intArray[1].hashCode()) { // comparison, <, >, ==
    // do whatever you want
}
```